# Find length of adjacent line in triange?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I have the following setup:
[image]
(We know every point, length and angle illustrated in the figure, expect for $z$)

I am then trying to figure out the length $z$ going from the point $X$ to the middle of the baseline.

Here is what I have managed to think myself:

The angle at $C$ and $C'$ in the small triangles are the same as the angle at $X$ in the triangle formed by $\overrightarrow{CXF}$ and $\overrightarrow{C'XF}$ where $F$ is a point in the middle of the baseline. That is, $\theta_1 = \theta_2$. I then thought that applying the definitions of sine, cosine or tangent might work but I would only know the opposite line of the triangle so wasn't a success. I got stuck here :(

Can anybody help me out?

As a matter of fact, I know that the answer should be $z = - \frac{f B}{x' - x}$ but do not know how it is derived, which is what I am interested in.

Comment: What is given here?

Comment: Ah, good question! We know everything but $z$ :) That is, we know $x$, $x'$, $f$, $C$, $C'$(and therefore also $B$), and $X$ - all letters you see in the figure expect for $z$

Comment: Is it given that $XC=XC'$ ?

Comment: It has not been said explicitly anywhere so would say no. Only that the things in the figure expect $z$ is known.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop a perpendicular from $X$ to the baseline. Call the base of the altitude $Y$.

We form two similar triangles, hence we have the equal ratios:

$$\frac fx = \frac z{CY}, \quad \frac f{x'} = \frac z{C'Y}$$

We also have $B = CY + C'Y = \dfrac {xz}f + \dfrac {x'z}f = z\left(\dfrac{x+x'}f\right)$.

Hence $z = \dfrac {fB}{x+ x'}$.

Comment: Thanks! Happy holidays!